# VSCode not showing correct import suggestions for a local linked package

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, es6-modules

VSCode is not offering import suggestions correctly for a package that was linked locally (using npm link).

Normally when I want to use a class from a package, I'd write `Foo` and press tab to automatically add the import for `myModule/Foo.js`. But in my current setup, I am not getting import suggestions for myModule at all.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
project
|-  server (node package)
|   |-  node_modules/
|   |-  src/
|   |-  package.json
|-  myModule (node package)
    |-  src/
    |-  package.json
```

All packages are of the module type (es6 import/exports).

```
"type": "module"
```

The myModule package uses a subpath export to hide the src folder:

```
"exports": {
  "./*": "./src/*"
}
```

Then I used `npm link` in `project/myModule`, followed by `npm link myModule` in `project/server`.
I can then use myModule in `server/src/index.js` as follows:

```
import Foo from "myModule/Foo.js"
import Four from "myModule/Bar/Four.js"
```

At this point, Node is happy. Unfortunately, VSCode is not. When using `Foo` or `Bar` and using the IntelliSense suggestion to automatically add the import, I get the following result:

- No import suggestions at all with the setup described above.
- VSCode adding an import through a relative path (E.g: `../../myModule/src/Foo.js`) if I remove the subpath export from myModule.
- I tried adding a `jsconfig.json` with a path alias like: `"myModule/*": ["./node_modules/myModule/src/*"]` or `"myModule/*": ["./node_modules/myModule/*"]` but unfortunately that didn't make a difference.

What can I do to have working import suggestions again in VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

Placing a jsconfig.json in `project/` with `"myModule/*": ["./myModule/src/*"]` as a path alias has made VSCode happy again.

This may present other challenges further down the line, as I'm now specifying this alias for every package in `project/`. Other suggestions are still very much welcome, as well as an explanation why jsconfig.json in `project/server/` was not working as expected.