# VSCode Intellisense not suggesting sub folder exports

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, package.json

I have a repo/module that I use to export TS types into another project. Both of these projects are TS with ESM. Relevant `tsconfig.json` part:

```
"target": "es2020",
"lib": ["es2020"],
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
```

And both `package.json` set to `"type": "module"`.

All my imports work fine but in an attempt to organize things I wish to place some of my type in a folder/master type:

```
export * as GraphQL from './types/graphql.js' // Ex: "GQLType"
export * from './types/foo.js' // Ex: FooType
export * from './types/bar.js' // Ex: BarType
```

My expectations when importing this types module in the main one is to be able to do something like:

```
import { FooType, BarType, GraphQL } from '...themodule"
```

I would use the `GraphQL` as `GraphQL.GQLType`.

It works fine but if I have say "GQLType" in my code the "quick fix" VSCode suggestion is not:

`Add import from "GraphQL"`

But instead:

`Add import from "themodule/dist/graphql.js"`

I've toyed wit the `exports` field in the types module to no avail.

is there a way for VSCode to be a little smarter about the quick fix? I really like to use the "Add all missing imports".

I did find this [VSCode not showing correct import suggestions for a local linked package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591202/vscode-not-showing-correct-import-suggestions-for-a-local-linked-package) but not really an answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was able to create a workaround.

In the imported module package.json:

```
 "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js",
    "./graphql": "./dist/graphql.js"
  },
```

And in my code, instead of using the namespace as I had it I can do:

```
import { FooType, BarType } from '...themodule"
import { GQLType } from '...themodule/graphql"
```

VSCode is able to offer the proper suggestions.